# How to change messaging and phone app in Oppo R9s?

Tags: sms, calls, stock-android, default-applications, oppo

Is there a way to change messaging and phone call apps without the phone defaulting to stock on an unrooted Oppo R9s?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever settings you change for the messaging will not make any difference, the phone will always revert to the default app. I took this up directly with OPPO and had the following response: 
*"We decided not to allow customer to set 3rd party applications as default message application, for security of the devices cannot be guaranteed. We also want to let you experience our built-in application and to be spared from the malfunction like virus, bug or etc."*

Not the response I wanted or expected!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to download an alternative app from the Play store and then replace it with the stock app in your app drawer. This way you will always open that app instead of the stock one. However this does not guarantee your incoming calls or messages will be received in that 3rd party app. You can try using Truecaller app though. It allows you to replace the stock app with it.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps for changing the default app for messaging :

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Select **Apps**
3. Select **Configure Apps** (Top Right icon)
4. Select **Default Apps** under **Advanced**
5. Tap on your messaging app

Now,the list of messaging apps will pop up which you have installed on your device. Select the one which you want to make default.

Repeat the same for the Calling app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot.  i have tried this but everytime a message or call comes through a message pops up saying phone has reset to stock defsult

Comment: Try clearing the defaults first. To clear the defaults, follow these steps: Go to **Settings** -> **Apps** -> Tap the app you want to clear from default -> Slide down and you will find **Launch/Open by default** -> Clear Defaults. After this, follow the steps that I mentioned in the answer.